# _stat fails on networked directory

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2008, lan

My program copies files from my Windows laptop to my Windows desktop over the LAN. I use drag&drop from Explorer to provide the source and destination.

The source is: `C:\Paul`

The destination is: `\\SERVER\Paul`

However, `_stat(dst,&dst_statbuf)` fails with `-1` and `errno` set to `ENOENT` (file not found).

Note that from Explorer drag & drop the paths provided are correct and exist, and in explorer I can see the destination directory and can open files so permissions seems OK.

Does anyone have any idea why `_stat` fails?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `_stat` does not write. Try to step into the `_stat` function and see to what win32 function is actually called, that may give you some hints. Does the `dst` file actually exist when you call `_stat`?

Comment: @MichaelWalz, it uses `_stat64i32`. The destination (a directory) exists.

Comment: Step further into the `_stat64i32` function until you encounter raw win32 functions.

Comment: for what you need `_stat` at all ? you can use `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` or `ZwQueryInformationFile` instead

Answer (score 4):

Found the problem.

In `stat64.c` (VC2008) there is the curious comment:

```
/* root dir. ('C:\') or UNC root dir. ('\\server\share\') */
```

followed by the call to an undocumented API function (line 145):

```
IsRootUNCName(path)
```

Indeed, appending a backslash to a *server path* makes `_stat` work. But note that calling `_stat` on a regular directory on the server path also works. So it only fails on the root of the share.

I consider this a bug (or at least an incongruency between Windows Explorer and `_stat`)

Comment: I confirm, with VS2017 and the UCRT I don't have this problem, it works with or without final backslash.

Comment: Not really that surprising. `C:` is different from `C:\`. The former is the current directory on drive `C`, the latter is the root of `C`. Read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I am not sure this applies. Your reference says "_A file name is relative to the current directory if it does not begin with ...a UNC name_" and specific to disk letters it says "_If a file name begins with only a disk designator but not the backslash after the colon, it is interpreted as a relative path to the current directory on the drive_"

Comment: Older versions of CRT call `FindFirstFile[Ex]` to get stat info. This function fails for volume and UNC root directories, so the CRT fakes the stat entry in this case. `IsRootUNCName` is a static function defined in stat64.c. It's called as part of verifying that a path is a valid root directory, and it actually returns true for a UNC path without a trailing slash. However, the subsequent `GetDriveType` call returns `DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR` (1). Since it's not a root directory to be faked, the stat call fails with `ENOENT`.

Comment: The new Universal CRT no longer uses `FindFirstFileEx`. Instead it calls `CreateFile` and gets stat info via `GetFileType` and `GetFileInformationByHandle`. This should work for root directories, but if for some reason it can't get a handle, it still defaults to returning a fake entry if the path is a valid root directory.

Comment: @eryksun, that's about the logic. Thanks for the detailed analysis.